# how to uninstall package lexik / jwt-authentication-bundle in my project symfony 4

Tags: symfony, jwt

I have installed package `lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle` by command `composer require lexik / jwt-authentication-bundle`, I find in packages folder a `lexik_jawt_authentication.yaml` file, and in `.env` file I find 3 line add

```
JWT_SECRET_KEY =% kernel.project_dir% / config / jwt / private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY =% kernel.project_dir% / config / jwt / public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE = training
```

now i want to uninstall this package i don't know how

Answer (score -2):

You can delete the package with composer.

> `composer lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove

Comment: I think you may have left out a rather important word in your answer.

Comment: There is an edit button in the lower left corner that you can use to update your answer.  However, due to the vagueness of the question, I'm pretty sure your answer is incomplete.  There may or may not need to be additional steps taken to remove a Symfony bundle.  I suspect that may be why someone has chosen to downvote your answer.